# Error installing mod-wsgi after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, apache2

I have a Django web app (perhaps you'd call it an intranet app on my home network), and I upgraded the host machine from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. Unfortunately, mod-wsgi got broken in the process. I've been trying to uninstall/reinstall it, but I just get an error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-wsgi (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-wsgi
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I haven't found much online about this problem. Any suggestions of how to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Does this help - `sudo apt-get remove --purge libapache2-mod-wsgi` ?

Comment: @Raphael: Yes, it did! Thank you! Make that an answer so I can upvote/accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To uninstall the package, type:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge libapache2-mod-wsgi`